# Why is my cube looking like this with the glass material?

Tags: glass

[image]I'm new at blender and am trying to make the cube look like glass. I'm not sure how to not make it look like a mirror and have this weird texture reflection. The monkey is a better picture with what is going on. It's leaving a reflection of a forest.[image]

Comment: maybe first don't make it metallic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate things.

Here is how you do it:

**Solution 01 (physically accurate)**
Use Principled BSDF shader

- Leave everything as is (very important)
- Set Transmission to 1
- Set Roughness as desired
  Boom, you have realistic glass.

**Solution 02 (old, not physically accurate)**
Use *Glass BSDF*

- Set roughness as desired

Example of both, side by side:
[image]

Tip:
If you're going for realism, use Principled BSDF wherever you can. It solves many issues for you such as fresnel, light fall-off, etc…

BlenderGuru [explains all of it’s nodes](https://youtu.be/4H5W6C_Mbck).

Comment: I figured it out. My rendering engine was set to Eevee, when I set to cycles it worked.

Comment: Sure thing. Evee currently doesn’t support glass-like material.
You can now mark this question as answered (for others with the same problem) :).