# How to print a graphic on a glass window

Tags: materials, uv

I have a glass window (a plane object) on which I want to print a graphic.

However, the glass turns black. below is a screenshot of the shader set-up I used. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164277/add-two-principled-bsdf-with-aplha/164279?noredirect=1#comment277527_164279

Comment: Consider using the shrinkwrap mod with a text image.

Comment: Don't use shrinkwrap you will end up with Z-fighting errors. To add an image with alpha channel to a material read: [add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447)

Comment: You can use the shrinkwrap modifier and add a small offset from the surface to avoid Z-fighting @cegaton

Comment: There is no need to have a new mesh, when dealing with textures.

Comment: just plug the color to the second socket of the color mix shader , not the first one, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wAut.jpg

Answer (score 3):

To make a proper glass pane:

1. Use a BW image instead of a transparent one
2. Use the *Mix Shader* node
3. Add some thickness to your glass pane, so it bends light like in reality

[image]

[image]

**Additional notes**

- It's better to use [Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156617/78972) if you're going for realism
- I used two materials so it looks better. Glass with white stripes for front face, and pure glass for the rest.

Comment: Hi! Just a quick sidenote: Adding manual line breaks to your post, probably breaks the layout of the website for a few devices. I didn't test it but I guess the website is created without such exception in mind. Cheers!